# How to add pagination to union tables in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pagination, union

How to add pagination to unionTable?

Usually i did something like this:

```
    $query = $this->db->get('tutorial', $num, $offset);
```

but i don`t know how to do it here help.

```
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM
             ($subQuery1 UNION $subQuery2 UNION $subQuery3)
             AS unionTable GROUP BY date DESC");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using Mysql, try the following code:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM
         ($subQuery1 UNION $subQuery2 UNION $subQuery3)
         AS unionTable GROUP BY date DESC LIMIT $num, $offset");
```

NOTICE: make sure that you have set the correct values to the variables $num and $offset before query.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so you're using `query` instead of `get`, and you will have to, in addition to 600Mhz answer of adding `$num` and `$offset` previously calculated, to retrieve the values from the active record query, so, you'll have to execute the query:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM
         ($subQuery1 UNION $subQuery2 UNION $subQuery3)
         AS unionTable GROUP BY date DESC LIMIT $num, $offset")
         ->result();
```

This way, it'll emulate the get function and `$query` will have the array of objects that you usually retrieve with get. If you already knew it, accept 600MHz answer, as it answered first, XD

Comment: Yes you are right, using query need to call result() to get the data array filled by the row data object. result_array() will return the data array contains the associated array of row values.