# Pagination in CodeIgniter with join tables

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Ok i wanna make pagination with join tables. I want to paginate results from two tables. My problem is how to pass the limit and offset into my model. My code so far:

CONTROLLER

```
$this->load->view('includes/nav_com2');

$this->load->model("Membership_model");

$this->load->library('pagination');

$config['base_url']= 'http://localhost/rip/home/comments';
$config['total_rows']= $this->db->get('comments')->num_rows;
$config['per_page']= 2;
$config['num_links']= 5;
$config['uri_segment'] = 3;
$this->pagination->initialize($config);

$data['records'] = $this->Membership_model->get_data($config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));
$this->load->view('comments',$data);
```

MODEL:

```
public function get_data(){

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT photos.image_min, users.username FROM photos JOIN comments on photos.users_id = comments.user_id JOIN users on users.id = photos.id ");
    return $query;

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add pagination to union tables in codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24941406/how-to-add-pagination-to-union-tables-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM
     anything GROUP BY date DESC LIMIT $num, $offset");
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following code..

```
    $this->db->select('photos.image_min, users.username');
    $this->db->from('photos');
    $this->db->join('comments', 'photos.users_id = comments.user');
    $this->db->join('users', 'photos.id = users.id');
    $this->db->limit($num, $offset);
    $method = 'result';
    return $this->db->get()->$method();
```